# select sum in sql server using one query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in my database with two columns as *int* for example `cal1` and `cal2`.

I make the sum from each row as in `select ( cal1 + cal2) from cat as total`, now I want to do the sum from all columns total if is possible.

Comment: From all new  rows total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the addition in the SUM :

```
SELECT SUM(cal1+cal2) AS total
  FROM cat
```

Comment: @naf-naf: are you sure this does what you want? I thought you wanted per row and the SUM of all rows in one go?

Comment: @naf-naf: who was that last comment for? Use the @ thing if me please. See my answer too

Comment: gbn, this does exactly what you describe. Edit: Sorry, I misunderstood your post (realized this after seeing your answer). You are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SUM(cal1) + SUM(cal2)) AS TotalSum FROM cat
```

Thats to sum the values of all rows together. If you want to sum all columns up, you have to specifically write their names into the column list.

Comment: I need to know each row alone, and also the all rows from the to collumns, With this example it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You want 2 totals in one go?

```
SELECT
   cal1+cal2 AS PerRowTotal,
   SUM(cal1+cal2) OVER () AS AllRowTotal
FROM
   cat
```